# Grunt выдает ошибку при сборке в корневой папки bootstrap

Tags: html, css, node.js, bootstrap, grunt

Пытаюсь собрать тестовый проект. Установил `node`, клонировал `bootstrap` с `GitHub`. Пытаюсь собрать проект с помощью `Grunt`(его тоже поставил). И он не работает при команде `Grunt` - выдает `Warning` :

> Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

При установки флага `--force`:

> Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.
>
> Done, but with warnings.

Но папка `dist` в каталоге все равно не появляется.

Как сделать, сделать что бы `Grunt` работал без ошибок и `warning`?

Comment: Очевидно у вас не создан дефолтный таск. Покажите содержимое файла gruntfile.js.